# Adobe Flash Player.app file alone, without being embedded into a .dmg package

Tags: adobe-flash

where can I download the Adobe Flash Player.app file NOT as a .dmg Installer package to put into the Applications folder.
I have done so with other files, but cannot seem to find the executable Flash Player file to put into the Applications folder.
I just want the .app file.

Comment: hmmm... I'm simply looking for the Adobe Flash Player.app file without the .dmg Installer package.

Comment: it just installs the Adobe Flash Player.app and not anything else (like the plug-in)!

Comment: yeah, I'd like to install the Adobe Flash Player.app file myself.  There is something wrong with my computer and .dmg files, so I can usually just grab whatever .app file I need or update and place it right into the Applications folder in the Mac HD.  It's worked just fine with other programs so far.

Comment: you might treat the causes instead of symptoms by rather asking a question regarding your dmg/installer packages problems...

Comment: ok.  how do I extract the .app file from the installer package without running the installer program?  or rather, can I hack the package and pull the .app file out?

Comment: you may download and install [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/cgi-bin/pacifist_download.cgi?type=zip) (it's a zip file!) and try to install the package with it.

Comment: it's shareware but afaik the first 14 days you are free to use it

Answer (score 0):

Adobe provides a standalone Flash Player: [Flash Player Projector 16.0](http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/16/flashplayer_16_sa.dmg).
Additional also debugger versions are [available](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) as well as older versions.

Originally it was meant for Flex and Flash developers.

Example: Starting a flash game

[image]